# I want to upload multiple images using express and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, file-upload

SO i have been following this tutorial by geeksforgeeks here is the link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/upload-and-retrieve-image-on-mongodb-using-mongoose/ but it shows how to upload one image at once, if i want to upload multiple images what should i do? Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

In this line:

```
app.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
```

instead of `upload.single` you can use

```
upload.array('image', 12)
```

Please check `multer` docs for all the details:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Thanks for your help